# .htaccess - how to force https

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, ssl

I want to redirect traffic to an ssl secured site for bookmywash.co.uk. I have searched how to do this on stack and google. I have seen a few codes that have not worked.

This is a wordpress site, sometimes when i try to navigate to the site from within the 1and1 web control panel the site goes to http s://bookmywash.co.uk/ and i get a An error occurred during a connection to bookmywash.co.uk. Peer reports it experienced an internal error. Error code: SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT error.

I contacted my host (1and1.co.uk) and was sent this [link](http://help.1and1.co.uk/ssl-certificates-c85276/administration-c85278/ssl-certificate-managed-by-1and1-c85280/redirect-traffic-to-an-ssl-secured-site-a627000.html)
Its states to use

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond % {HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC] RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http: //www.domain. com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

the code above doesn't work and maybe i am not editing correctly. My full .htccess file content is below:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/javascript A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/x-js A2419200
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
    ExpiresByType video/asf A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/avi A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/java A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/divx A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/msword A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/gif A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/json A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A2419200
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/png A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A2419200
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-opentype A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A2419200
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/font-woff A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A2419200
    ExpiresByType application/zip A2419200
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R,L]

    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

AddHandler x-mapp-php5.5  .php
```

Thanks alot for your help

Comment: An update on the above issue. I spoke to 1and1 about 7 times this week.1and1 wrote to me today saying "We sincerely apologize for the inconvenience this technical glitch has brought you. This is a bug on the system that is already known and reported to our developers. At the moment, we dnt have an estimated time frame for the fix however rest assured that we are currently working on a resolution. Once we have the fix, it will be implemented to all affected customers. To ensure that your case will be taken cared of, I will be adding the details of your case to the list of affected customers"